# Join elements in array

Tags: ruby, string

I have an array in Ruby, like `["dog", "cat", bat"]`. How can I join them into a single string with words separated by spaces, like `"dog cat bat"`? I know it's easy to iterate over the elements and join them one-by-one, but is there a one-line way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = ["dog", "cat", "bat"]
a.join(" ") #=> "dog cat bat"
```

Answer (score 2):

Cute shortcut:

```
["dog", "cat", "bat"] * ' '
#=> "dog cat bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

["dog", "cat", "bat"].join ' '